# What does "SS" mean in box 5 of the WD AGO 53-55 form?

Tags: world-war-two

I have my father's [WD AGO 53-55](https://www.archives.gov/personnel-records-center/dd-214) form. He was a WWII D Day veteran. I have not been able to decipher the Component code in Box 5. I've seen many examples with AUS (for Army of the United States) and a few other codes. His shows as SS. Can anyone tell me what SS stands for in the Component box?

Answer (score 2):

If **Box 27 - Local SS (Draft) Board & Number**, is filled out, then the *SS* probably just means [Selective Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Service_System).

Link: [Reading and Understanding WW2 Discharge Documents](https://www.80thdivision.com/pdfs/ReadingUnderstandingWWIIDischargeDocument.pdf)